# why does this code <a target="Open in New Window"> opens in a new window?

Tags: html, href, target

I forgot to replace the words "Open in a New Window" with `_blank` when testing a system and I found that even though the html looks as such, it still opens in a new tab.

```
<a target="Open in New Window" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqxty4mb/) to see for yourself!

note: I'm using latest Firefox on OSX.  I also tested in Chrome in which case it also works.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Do you have you browser's default behavior set to do that?

Comment: Depends on the browser and how you have it set up.  The html only requests the browser to open a new window - it can do what it likes with the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Because if it's not a known parameter it takes it as a window name and create a new window as none of that name are available.

Answer (score 1):

As per the following specification, a target parameter that doesn't exist has a default effect of opening in a new window.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name-or-keyword

The specification also lists out the behavior of all the other possibilities.

Comment: As the cited document says, a new browsing context is opened, not necessarily a new window. Quite often these days, browsers open a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because if the target is set, it will always open up in the window identified by what you put in the target. So, you're opening it up in a new window identified by "Open in New Window".